# 14-50 outlet -- ok to mount on floor?

Tags: electrical

Is it ok to mount this on the floor under the range?

Or must it go on wall?

[image]

Comment: @knowitall It is for a range. Voltage is either 120/240 (most of US/Canada) or small possibility 120/208. Current (which you didn't ask) is nominally 50A, but 14-50 can also be used for 40A circuits because there is no "14-40".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact wow, that is 50 Amp plug ? why such funny shape ?

Comment: @knowitall The "funny shapes" of [NEMA connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#NEMA_14) are so that you can't plug something into the wrong receptacle. NEMA 5-15 and 5-20 are an exception - the 5-20 receptacle can accept 5-15 plugs. But pretty much everything else is designed to be very specific so you can't mix up 120V and 240V or 30A and 50A, etc.

Comment: @knowitall the raised part is probably to support the cable ... it would keep the plug fully inserted into the socket ... if the cable was not supported, then it would cause the plug to sit at an angle in the socket

Comment: Brand & model of the receptacle, or at least a picture of the installation instructions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 12):

Generally speaking, if a receptacle does not have instructions that include floor mounting, that is not allowed. The usual problem is *water*. A receptacle on the floor, especially in a kitchen, is far more likely to get water (overflowing sink, spills, mopping the floor, etc.) than a receptacle on the wall.

Comment: Instructions for this model say, wall mount

Comment: @knowitall I know that. I am explaining *why* (or at least one very common reason why) so that people who find this question later, perhaps about a different model of receptacle, can get some useful information.

Comment: The NEC has no minimum height and this because inside a dwelling is normally considered a dry location it has nothing to do with wet. The position of the receptacle facing up is normally the problem but it can be mounted on its side to a wall and be 100% code compliant.

Answer (score 5):

The listing instructions are needed:

many can be floor mounted but most have to be along a wall (receptacle not facing up) these state wall mount they can be at floor level.

There is no minimum height to mount them but an inspector may reference the receptacles can not be in a counter facing up unless listed for that orientation and they use the same reasoning for this. In this case they can be wall mounted sideways and then they are 2” tall and wall mounted meeting code.

Comment: Not this model. I has to be wall mounted according to the specs

Comment: Knowitall, you did not read my answer I stated along the wall this is considered a horizontal wall mount at floor level and is allowed notice the instructions do not provide a specific horizontal or vertical mount as I said surface (wall) as the opening normally can not face up as that fixture would require for a “floor mount” but it can be mounted at the floor level vertically or horizontally to the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Found your Power Outlet model at Home Depo

Pass & Seymour 50 Amp 125/250-Volt NEMA 14-50R Surface Mount Power Outlet

[image: socket]

The instruction says "Wall Mount"

[image: wall]

The word "Surface mount" can be misunderstood.

Comment: A wall mount can be attached horizontally at the floor level  to the wall. yes I have done this dozens of times on permitted jobs in multiple states.